# How to get measurement result one by one in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

For example, run the following code:

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
transpiled_qc = transpile(circ, backend)
job = backend.run(transpiled_qc, shots=100)
counts = job.result().get_counts()
```

and we could get:

```
{'100000': 41, '011101': 2, '110001': 1, ...}
```

But in this algorithm we want to get the measurement results one by one,  and "get_counts()" function merges the repeating quantum states. It is similar to setting shot = 1, and then repeating this circuit 100 times. How to achieve this function? Any help will be appreciate!

P.S. Setting `shots=1` and repeating 100 times will cause the slow-speed, it doesn't look like a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the backend supports the option `memory`, such like Aer, you can get the result of each shot in the following way:

```
job = backend.run(transpiled_qc, shots=100, memory=True)
results = job.result().get_memory()
print(results)
```

```
['100000', '1100010', ... ]
```